# Rules for determining the set of function type compatible with std::function<R(T1,T2)>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, implicit-conversion, type-erasure

Suppose if I have this,

```
std::function<int(int,int)> fs;
```

then how can I determine the set of functions (or function objects) which `fs` can be initialized with?

Which of the folllowing is allowed and which not:

```
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](int, int) { return int(10); };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](char, char) { return char(10); };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](int, short) { return int(10); };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](double, int) { return float(10); };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](int, wchar_t) { return wchar_t(10); };

std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](const char*, int){ return "string"; };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](const char*, int){ return 10; };
std::function<int(int,int)> fs = [](const char*, int){ return std::string(); };
```

Of course, I can compile and see which one compiles fine, and which doesn't. But that doesn't help me understanding the variations in the types of parameters and return type. How far can I go to use different types for them?

To put it in other words, if I've given a function (or function object), how can I determine at compile-time if it is compatible with `std::function<int(int,int)>` or not? I've little understanding, but I'm not confident enough.

So please help me understanding and laying out the rules for determining the set of function type compatible with `std::function<R(T1,T2)>`?  Can metaprogramming help me here to notify users, generating nice error messages, if they use incompatible function?

By the way, the first group seems to be compatible : http://ideone.com/hJpG3

Answer (score 4):

The object (function pointer or functor) must be Callable with the given argument types, i.e. `fun( declval< Types >() ... )` is well-formed and implicitly convertible to `R`.

See C++11 §20.8.2 in particular; it gives various special cases for pointers-to-members, etc. §20.8.11.2/2 and 20.8.11.2.1/7 tie this to the `std::function` constructor.

Answer (score 4):

There is no pre-packaged metaprogramming solution.  I've programmed up the following traits to help with this question.  These traits simply implement the sections referred to in Potatoswatter's answer.  The code comments even enumerate the bullet points in the referenced sections.

```
template <class _F, class ..._Args> struct __invokable;
template <class _F, class ..._Args> struct __invoke_of;
```

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/type_traits

I've used these to create a private "member trait" of `std::function`:

```
template <class _F, bool = __invokable<_F&, _ArgTypes...>::value>
    struct __callable;
```

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/functional

It has occurred to me that these might make good tr2 material (sans the leading underscores).  If you agree, perhaps you should let your National Body representative know.

If you would like to use these traits, the code is open source.  But I would appreciate it if you respect the open source license by including the copyright information in each file.

Comment: It seems this answer is in the context of functionality exposed by the Standard Library… if my answer is incorrect, could you comment on why? Edit - this trait appears to neglect the return value conversion…

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I just reviewed the implementation of these traits.  They depend on `std::forward`, `std::is_convertible` and `std::is_same`.  They could be implemented as part of a std::lib or not.  I've also reviewed my answer and am not seeing where I implied that your answer is incorrect.  My answer simply provides a metaprogramming implementation of the sections you refer to.  The OP asked about a metaprogramming solution, so I thought my answer relevant.  On the return value conversion:  This is covered in `__callable` by using `__invoke_of` and `is_convertible`.

Comment: Okay. The only disagreement would be that I consider my response to be the "pre-packaged standard answer." As for return type conversion, I didn't follow the link and assumed it was a non-member template, with no access to the desired return type. At the user level, isn't `std::is_convertible< typename std::result_of< F( Args ... ) >::type, R >::value` sufficient? I guess it depends if you want SFINAE or a `false` result.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: It is true that `result_of<F(Args...)>` is roughly the same as `__invoke_of<F, Args...>`.  For whatever reasons I've found `result_of` confusing and clumsy to work with, especially when `F` is a pointer to member data or pointer to member function.  It has been about a year since I was last knee-deep in this area and don't recall for sure if they are exactly substitutable or not.